# Trim string before character in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, substring, rfc3339

I have this date/time string

```
$dateTime = '2016-11-01T16:00:59:999000Z';
```

I would like to be able to remove the **3 digits before the `Z`**.
Not really sure how to do that. I was trying to rework this:

```
substr($dateTime, 0, -3);
```

but couldn't figure out how to make it trim before the `Z` and not at the end of the string.

Comment: Hey, not sure how many times this code is being iterated but http://stackoverflow.com/a/40305677/2191572 is the slowest, followed by http://stackoverflow.com/a/40305493/2191572, and http://stackoverflow.com/a/40305555/2191572 is the fastest. 100k iterations in PHP 5.6.20 gives .173 seconds, .039 seconds, and .025 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```php
preg_replace("/\d{3}(Z)($)?/", "$1$2", "2016-11-01T16:00:59:999000Z");
// Result: 2016-11-01T16:00:59:999Z
```

Should do the job even if `Z` will be not in the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can just `subtr()` the string twice if you know that the unwanted `000` is ALWAYS going to be in the same position:

```
<?php
$date = '2016-11-01T16:00:59:999000Z';

echo substr($date, 0, -4).substr($date, -1); // this produces 2016-11-01T16:00:59:999Z

// substr($date, 0, -4) produces 2016-11-01T16:00:59:999
// the period "." is the concatenation operator
// substr($date, -1) produces Z
```

Answer (score 1):

```
substr_replace($dateTime, '', -4, 3);
```

Comment: I like this better than my own answer but I cannot upvote unless you provide an explanation.

Comment: :) the requirement was to remove 3 digits before Z. substr_replace at first find those substring and replaced by empty string: For reference http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php

Comment: Yes, I know; I can read your code. Add a comment your code so that OP can easily read and understand for the future. See my answer for an example of good comments.

Comment: Thanks for your advice :) I will remember

Answer (score 0):

```
$dateTime = '2016-11-01T16:00:59:999000Z';

$result = substr($dateTime, 0, 23).$dateTime[strlen($dateTime)-1];
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.